Help me identify an unknown 8 pin SMD component
I have this 8-pin component on a battery management board. I suspect it is a two-channel MOSFET.
The battery charger input is spread over three pins on one side. The remaining pin on that side is probably an 'enable' pin.
The output is spread over the four pins on the other side, which go to the battery \$+V_e\$ terminal.
The marking is P5549P.
As for the manufacturer, I have no idea what that logo is, maybe "KvM'or 'hvM'


The set of 1 pin, 3 pins, 4 pins strongly suggests it is one MOSFET. 1 pin = gate, 3 pins = source, 4 pins = drain.

I received an answer from the manufacturer of the MCU that is used in the board.

It's a P-channel MOS with SOP8 package. The manufacture is Huamei, which is a small local MOSFET brand. Their products used to be pretty popular in domestic power tools application, however, they gradually exited this market for poor margin.

Looking on element14's site I see that this would work: SI4435DY 30 V,  12.6 A power MOSFET.
As it turned out I purchased the STS6P3LLH6, 30 V, 6 A.

I think you might be looking for the SSFQ4559 60V N-Channel + P-Channel Complementary MOSFET. Just google P5549p/SOP-8, you could also try and measure the electrical characteristics and checking if they match. Assuming, of course, it's neither broken nor absolutely crucial for it to stay intact.

EE Stack Exchange answers are typically expected to be 'self-contained' and not rely on external links. Please edit the relevant details into your answer.

What makes you think it's the SSFQ4559? The datasheet on the homepage you linked states that the marking is Q4559.

It (the datasheet I linked) was referenced on a website by some Chinese manufactuerer, I cant find the website right now, unfortunately. The only thing I did now find mentioning the specific number and with the brand name also fitting (arguably anyway) is the HM P5549P/SOP-8. I couldn't find any datasheet there though.
